# How to return offset char_indices from a function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Suppose the following Rust snippet:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn char_indices_from(s: &str, offset: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item=(usize, char)> + '_ {
    s[offset..].char_indices().map(move |(i,c)| (i+offset,c))
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = Cow::from("watermelons and stuff");
    let offset = 2;
    for (i, c) in char_indices_from(&m, offset) {
        if i == 3 {
            m = Cow::from("clouds and the sky");
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This displeases the borrow checker:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `m` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
10 |     for (i, c) in char_indices_from(&m, offset) {
   |                   -----------------------------
   |                   |                 |
   |                   |                 borrow of `m` occurs here
   |                   a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
11 |         if i == 3 {
12 |             m = Cow::from("clouds and the sky");
   |             ^ assignment to borrowed `m` occurs here
...
15 |     }
   |     - ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl Iterator<Item = (usize, char)>`
```

Doing this, however, works just fine:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let mut m = Cow::from("watermelons and stuff");
    let offset = 2;
    for (i, c) in m[offset..].char_indices().map(|(i,c)| (i+offset, c)) {
        if i == 3 {
            m = Cow::from("clouds and the sky");
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Those are some excellent diagnostics given by `rustc`. Nevertheless, I find myself confused as to how one would fix `char_indices_from` such that the first program satisfies Rust's borrowing rules.

Comment: There are *many* ways to rewrite this. The question is, which one is useful for you? The context matters. For example, move the assignment out of the loop.

Comment: I'm equally interested in all solutions actually, since this is for learning purposes!

Comment: Why do you need `Cow` here?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Well, let's say this is a pretty heavily boiled-down version of what I'm really doing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is that you can overwrite `m` because it's the last thing you do before `break`.

It's true that the Rust borrow checker is smart enough to figure this out; your second example proves this.

The borrow checker rightfully complains about the first example, though, because you forget destructors, meaning, the `Drop` trait. Because your return type is `impl Iterator + '_`, it has to assume this could be any type that implements `Iterator` and depends on the input lifetimes. Which includes types that use the borrowed values in their `Drop` implementation. This is also what the compiler tries to tell you.

You could fix that by replacing the `impl` return type with the actual type, proving to the borrow checker that there is no `Drop` implementation. Although you will also get problems with that, because your type contains a closure whose type cannot be named.

That's why usually these things return their own iterator type (for example the `itertools` crate, [none of their functions have an `impl` return type](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html)).

So that's what I would do: implement your own iterator return type.

```rust
use std::{borrow::Cow, str::CharIndices};

struct CharIndicesFrom<'a> {
    raw_indices: CharIndices<'a>,
    offset: usize,
}

impl Iterator for CharIndicesFrom<'_> {
    type Item = (usize, char);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.raw_indices.next().map(|(i, c)| (i + self.offset, c))
    }
}

fn char_indices_from(s: &str, offset: usize) -> CharIndicesFrom<'_> {
    CharIndicesFrom {
        raw_indices: s[offset..].char_indices(),
        offset,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = Cow::from("watermelons and stuff");
    let offset = 2;
    for (i, c) in char_indices_from(&m, offset) {
        if i == 3 {
            m = Cow::from("clouds and the sky");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted for the explanation, but I'm opposed to this solution :)

Comment: Why? It's pretty much standard. What's your alternative?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have enough details. I don't like introducing a named iterator for one use.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Also I don't think there is an alternative ... the only way of telling the compiler that no `Drop` exists is by naming the iterator. And I don't think there is a cleaner way to do that, given that you can't name closures.

Comment: If I'd put that in a library / utils mod, I'd go even one step further and implement a `AsRef<str>` extension for it, this integrates it seemless like `char_indices`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa231759f66faa030b36d489d2ee4c7d